# how to handle axios onError in nuxtjs plugin and show appropriate error message to user

Tags: error-handling, axios, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt single page application. The api that I work with has a list of codes for various errors. So, in onError interceptor, the error has to be checked in a dictionary or in a more desired way in a json file. For this, I added a `error-handler.js` plugin in my nuxt project. But, I don't know how to read from json file.

1) Loading of the json file would occur every time an error thrown?

2) What is the best practice to show the error message to the user? Is this plugin only responsible to create the `error-message` and in the page `try-catch` is needed to toast that message?

```js
export default function ({ $axios, store, app, redirect }) {

  $axios.onError(error => {

    if (error.config.hasOwnProperty('errorHandle') && error.config.errorHandle === false) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    if (error.message === 'Network Error') {
      error.message = 'check the Internet connection';
      return
    }

    const code = parseInt(error.response && error.response.status)
    if (error.response)
      console.log('error.response', error.response.status, error.response)

    if (error.response.data.Errors) {
      let errMessage = ''
      error.response.data.Errors.forEach(item => {

        switch (item.Message.MessageText) {

             case 'OrganizationNotFound':
             errMessage = 'the organization that you are looking for does not exists'
            break
        }
      })
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Try to look into this article -> https://zaengle.com/blog/error-handling-in-nuxt-apps
also it's easy to introduce error handling by NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zaengle/error-handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Nuxt, plugin code is loaded once or twice per user visit, after that in universal mode it is not executed (of course your onError handler will be). It's once if you make it a client/server-side only plugin, or twice if you need it both on client and server. In your case client-side only plugin sounds like a good choice - just make sure that loading of JSON goes outside of the onError function.

As for how to show it, it depends on your design. We are using Vuetify and have v-snackbar in default layout so it's on every page. Snackbar is bound to VueX value. Then your error plugin can populate that value as appropriate as it will have access to store. This keeps the "raising the error" (dispatch to store) and "showing the error" reasonably decoupled, whilst very reusable (components can also dispatch to store if they face a problem).

Comment: thank you. I've been using snackbar and vuex separately, but I had never used this option to implement a global snakbar. With this, error messages shows regardless of page. Currently, I'm working on loading the json file in the plugin.

Comment: hi, just to be clear, you can absolutely tune this somewhat to fit your exact needs if you don't want it to show regardless of page - e.g. you could create "error-in-snackbar" component that you'd only embed in some pages, you could have multiple error sections in vuex etc. 
Overall, there are quite a few aspects/issues in your question so feel free to ask for more details if the generic / high-level description here is not sufficient :)

Comment: I've tried to show error messages with `vue-sweetalert/nuxt` but no success results :(, it looks like app.$swal is not available from axios plugin.

Comment: Try to look into this article -> zaengle.com/blog/error-handling-in-nuxt-apps also it's easy to introduce error handling by NPM package npmjs.com/package/@zaengle/error-handler